# Handling multiple '\000' in string with increasing ASCII value

Tags: c, string, data-structures

I am developing an application in which i came across the string which contains the multiple '\000' terminating character in between. I want that null character in the string.
As the while processing this, string terminates at the '\000' only, so i am trying to increase the ASCII value of it. But when i do it, i got the segmentation fault.

I have write code segment below as

```
 char *content; 
 content = malloc(8);
 content = "\037\000\000\000\000\037\037\037";
 int content_length = 8;
 content[1] = content[1] + 1;    // Increasing the ASCII value
```

Here if i remove the last line which increases the ASCII value, i get only 1 byte recieved in my application. So have changed the second byte (content[1]) then 2 bytes should be transferred, but i get the segmentation fault.

Am i doing something wrong? Does the hex or octal numbers make such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create storage. Either initialise an array with it:

```
char content[] = "\037\000\000\000\000\037\037\037";
```

Or if you want to use `malloc` rather than an array, you can use `memcpy` to copy the exact number of bytes:

```
memcpy(content, "\037\000\000\000\000\037\037\037", 8);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"\037\000\000\000\000\037\037\037"
```

is a string literal. String literals are non modifiable in C. Writing to a string literal is undefined behavior.

Then:

```
content = malloc(8);
content = "\037\000\000\000\000\037\037\037";
```

You get some memory from `malloc` but you are overwriting your pointer object to make it point elsewehere (the string literal), that's called a *memory leak*.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Definitely. First, you re-assign the `content` pointer to something else, effectively **leaking the allocated memory.**

Second, strings between quotes are string literals of which the content can't be modified. Your program invokes undefined behavior.